# Implementing swap() for objects with internal pointers

Tags: c++, swap

I'm implementing the [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) for `operator=` of a small non-owning-memory-referencing object I've designed.  When `MemRef` is referencing a piece of a buffer whose lifetime I trust, `_ptr` points into the buffer, as you'd expect.

What is unusual about this `MemRef` is that it consists not only of a `_ptr` and a `_len`, but also a `_memory` `std::string`: there are certain users (or situations) of this class whom I *do not* trust to protect their memory; for them, I actually copy their memory into the `_memory` string during construction, and set `_ptr = _memory.c_str()`.  I can always determine whether I have an "inref" MemRef (referring to its internal memory) or an "exref" MemRef (referring to some external buffer) by asking if `_ptr == _memory.c_str()`.

I'm confused about how to write the swap routine.  The following is taken from [copy-and-swap idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom):

Here's `operator=`:

```
MemRef&
MemRef::operator=(MemRef other) { 
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}
```

Here's the copy constructor:

```
// Copy ctor
MemRef::MemRef(const MemRef& other) :
    _memory(other._memory),
    _ptr(other._ptr),
    _len(other._len)
{   // Special provision if copying an "inref" MemRef
    if (other._ptr == other._memory.c_str()) {
        _ptr = _memory.c_str();
    }
}
```

And here's my `swap(first, second)` - which I believe needs more work.

```
void
swap(MemRef& first, MemRef& second) {
    using std::swap;
    swap(first._memory, second._memory);
    swap(first._ptr, second._ptr);
    swap(first._len, second._len);
}
```

So if I have:

```
MemRef mr_a("foo"); // creates an "inref" memref
MemRef mr_b(buffer_ptr, length); // creates an "exref" memref -> "blarch"
mr_a = mr_b;
```

`operator=()` gets called with a temporary MemRef built by copy-constructing mr_b; it calls `swap(mr_a, mr_b_copy);` `swap()` exchanges the pointer, length, and string (so that mr_a's former contents will be destructed along with mr_b_copy).

What I don't understand is whether the pointers in mr_a and mr_b_copy are correct at this point, or if they're tangled up with each other.

**UPDATE 1**: The above example doesn't illustrate the problem.  Consider this one:

```
MemRef mr_a;  // creates a memref with _ptr(NULL), _len(0)
mr_a = "woof"; //
```

For passing by value to operator=(), a temporary **inref** is constructed for "woof" and bound to the parameter `other`.  Then, references to `mr_a` and to `other` are passed to swap() and bound as `first` and `second` respectively.  After the swap, `first._ptr` was ... well, *wrong*.  Pointing to garbage.  Here's what I had to do:

```
void
swap(MemRef& first, MemRef& second) {
    using std::swap;

    // second is an exref
    if (second._ptr != second._memory.c_str()) {    
        swap(first._memory, second._memory);
        swap(first._len, second._len);
        swap(first._ptr, second._ptr);
    }
    // second is an inref
    else {
        swap(first._memory, second._memory);
        swap(first._len, second._len);
        first._ptr = first._memory.c_str();
    }
}
```

All I can conclude is that std::swap(string, string) is doing something strange.

Comment: @Mat: I believe it does, because the RHS is passed to operator=() *by value*.  That's part of the trick to the "copy and swap idiom", I gather.  See the link.

Comment: I'm not really sure why they wouldn't be - you seem to have the copyswap idiom pretty down if I'm reading you correctly. `mr_a` changes from an inref to an exref and I'm not sure if that's what you intended - what exactly do you feel like you're doing wrong?

Comment: @CommanderCorianderSalamander: I added UPDATE 1 to illustrate where I was actually having the problem.  For some reason, a simple swapping of the three components, when `second` is an inref, seems to leave first._ptr pointing to garbage.  The same address, but now there's garbage.  It's as if swapping strings is moving more than just the "handle" around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the update to the question, I think I can see what the problem is =)

In your initial `swap()` function, you had these lines:

```
swap(first._memory, second._memory);
swap(first._ptr, second._ptr);
swap(first._len, second._len);
```

If these were exrefs, all was well and good - swap would be executed as planned. However, if one was an inref (for now, we'll use the example you provided), then this was going on:

In these lines:

```
MemRef mr_a;  // creates a memref with _ptr(NULL), _len(0)
mr_a = "woof";
```

as you said correctly, a temporary **inref** was created from "woof", with its `_ptr` variable pointing to the beginning of `_memory.c_str()`.

Now, when your `swap()` gets called, first this happens:

```
swap(first._memory, second._memory);
```

So far all good. You've swapped the strings - but their **addresses** haven't changed, only their **contents**. From the standard:

`References, pointers, and iterators referring to the elements of a
basic_string sequence may be invalidated by the following uses of that
basic_string object: — As an argument to non-member functions swap()...` [C++ International Standard n1905](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1905.pdf)

So now, during the line

```
swap(first._ptr, second._ptr);
```

you introduce the prolem. Those are pointing to somewhere undefined - by swapping the string, we **invalidate** any pointers/iterators/references to the string or its members, including c_str() - but we **definitely** don't swap the nemory locations. So, swapping the pointers is wrong in this case, as you realized.

Fortunately, you've already solved the problem - by resetting the pointers in the case of an inref instead of swapping them, you avoid pointing to invalidated memory locations, and all problems are resolved! Hopefully this clears up what was going on though =)

edit: added standard reference and clarified!

Comment: Nice work!  I think that, if I were being thorough, I should apply the same logic to `second`; however, since `swap` is only being used by `operator=`, and `second` will be destructed when `operator=` exits, it's not strictly necessary.  Anyway, now that I understand why my solution worked, I'm a bit more confident of it :-)